Need help identifying small component on hot tub wall
I have a small (125 gal) Morgan hot tub, and there is a little round "something" on the wall that is wired to the top side control. I don't know what it is or does, but the wire is very frayed and about to break.
I'm attaching a picture in hopes that someone knows what it is. I didn't measure, but it's probably 2 1/2 inches in diameter.


Tried asking the manufacturer yet?

are there any labels where the wire connects?

Looks like a thermowell to me. Basically inside that metal tube would be a thermocouple to sense temperature for the controls. Does the unit have a digital temperature control feature?
